# Update not working as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In our table we have a field with length of nvarchar(70) which is used to store multiple values that can be queried using SUBSTRING. There are already 54 characters in the field including the final quote.

The Start and end characters of the field are always a single quote.

I need to update the field, adding up to 3 characters from another reference table. I tried the below, but it is missing of the last character when the number is greater than 9.

```
update Hermes_Rep.dbo.ActData
set spare6= LEFT(Spare6+space(56),55) + 
    isnull(YAR.YARPEP,' ') + isnull(cast(YAR.YARSCOR as nvarchar(2)),'  ')
    + '''' 
FROM Hermes_Rep.dbo.ACTdata 
LEFT JOIN KFILDTO_YARPF YAR ON ACTdata.ACNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS= YAR.YARCUS COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
WHERE DataDate= @ProcessDate
```

For example, if the data I am adding is `N9'` it works, but if the data is `N11'` it only puts in N1 So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not adding any data in this query.  This should just be padding the existing value with spaces.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry, I pasted the wrong code block from SSMS bu mistake.

Comment: This expression trancates your initial string to as maximum as 2 characters `cast(YAR.YARSCOR as nvarchar(2))`

Comment: well Serg, that is the maximum size of that field in the reference table. But I worked out the issue was the `LEFT(Spare6+space(56),55)` and changed the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the problemwas caused by the field being truncated by the `LEFT` function:

```
LEFT(Spare6+space(56),55)
```

so I changed it to

```
LEFT(Spare6+space(57),57)
```

and now it works.